# Are there sources which analyze in depth the significance of Allah's names coming in pairs?

Tags: quran, tafseer, asma-ul-husna

For example:

> Our Lord, and send among them a messenger from themselves who will
>   recite to them Your verses and teach them the Book and wisdom and
>   purify them. Indeed, You are the **Exalted in Might, the Wise**."
>   (2:129)

We can safely assume that these pairs do not appear randomly. We can equally safely assume that their **order** do not appear randomly. In various lectures I remember hearing that there is great wisdom in these pairs as well as their orders—so much so, that when we see them we should pause and ponder as to why they are specifically chosen by Allah.

Are there English sources which analyze in depth the significance of Allah's names coming in pairs? (If there are only Arabic sources, I would also like to know them.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are sources in Islamic scholarship that analyze the significance of Allah's names coming in pairs. The names of Allah are considered sacred and highly significant in Islamic theology, and their study and analysis has been a subject of Islamic scholarship for centuries.

One source that discusses the pairs of Allah's names is the book "Al-Qawl al-Mufid fi Adillat al-Tawhid" by the 18th-century Islamic scholar Muhammad ibn Abdul Wahhab. In this book, the author discusses the pairs of Allah's names and their significance in relation to the concept of Tawhid (the oneness of Allah). He explains that each pair of names represents a particular aspect of Allah's attributes and characteristics, and that understanding these pairs is important for gaining a deeper understanding of Allah and His oneness.

Another source that discusses the pairs of Allah's names is the book "The Ninety-Nine Beautiful Names of God" by the 14th-century Islamic scholar Ibn al-Qayyim. In this book, the author analyzes each of the 99 names of Allah and their pairs, and discusses their significance in relation to different aspects of Islamic theology and spirituality.

There are also various online resources and scholarly articles that analyze the significance of Allah's names coming in pairs, drawing from a wide range of Islamic sources and perspectives. These sources often discuss the deeper meanings and implications of each pair of names, and how they contribute to a fuller understanding of Allah and His attributes.
To find out more about this please follow the link:
https://www.islamiqate.com/4280/does-allah-have-more-than-99-names